# I created my custom incoming call screen with two buttons. How to i make the buttons answer and end a call?

Tags: android

I created a custom incoming call screen that get called on incoming call, but how can i handle the action to answer and end a call within my custom screen?

Answer (score 0):

*Side Note: Always go through Developer Docs they most of the time have answers for you. Even this one*

First of all you need to  have the permission to make and accept such calls,

Permission:

```
<manifest … >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>
</manifest>
```

Then you need to declare a service :

```
<service android:name="com.example.MyConnectionService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Afterwards follow these steps:

Complete guide is here [Build a calling app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged)

> Your calling app must provide an implemention of the ConnectionService
> class that the telecom subsystem can bind to. Your ConnectionService
> implementation should override the following methods:
>
> onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle, ConnectionRequest) The
> telecom subsystem calls this method in response to your app calling
> placeCall(Uri, Bundle) to create a new outgoing call. Your app returns
> a new instance of your Connection class implementation (for more
> information, see Implement the connection) to represent the new
> outgoing call. You can further customize the outgoing connection by
> performing the following actions:
>
> Your app should call the setConnectionProperties(int) method with the
> PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED constant as the argument to indicate that the
> connection originated from a calling app. If your app supports putting
> calls on hold, call the setConnectionCapabilities(int) method and set
> the argument to the bit mask value of the CAPABILITY_HOLD and
> CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD constants. To set the name of the caller, use
> the setCallerDisplayName(String, int) method passing the
> PRESENTATION_ALLOWED constant as the int parameter to indicate that
> the caller's name should be shown. To ensure that the outgoing call
> has the appropriate video state, call the setVideoState(int) method of
> the Connection object and send the value returned by the
> getVideoState() method of the ConnectionRequest object.
> onCreateOutgoingConnectionFailed(PhoneAccountHandle,
> ConnectionRequest) The telecom subsystem calls this method when your
> app calls the placeCall(Uri, Bundle) method and the outgoing call
> cannot be placed. In response to this situation, your app should
> inform the user (for example, using an alert box or toast) that the
> outgoing call could not be placed. Your app may not be able to place a
> call if there is an ongoing emergency call, or if there is an ongoing
> call in another app which cannot be put on hold before placing your
> call.
>
> onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle, ConnectionRequest) The
> telecom subsystem calls this method when your app calls the
> addNewIncomingCall(PhoneAccountHandle, Bundle) method to inform the
> system of a new incoming call in your app. Your app returns a new
> instance of your Connection implementation (for more information, see
> Implement the connection) to represent the new incoming call. You can
> further customize the incoming connection by performing the following
> actions:
>
> Your app should call the setConnectionProperties(int) method with the
> PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED constant as the argument to indicate that the
> connection originated from a calling app. If your app supports putting
> calls on hold, call the setConnectionCapabilities(int) method and set
> the argument to the bit mask value of the CAPABILITY_HOLD and
> CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD constants. To set the name of the caller, use
> the setCallerDisplayName(String, int) method passing the
> PRESENTATION_ALLOWED constant as the int parameter to indicate that
> the caller's name should be shown. To specify the phone number or
> address of the incoming call, use the setAddress(Uri, int) method of
> the Connection object. To ensure that the outgoing call has the
> appropriate video state, call the setVideoState(int) method of the
> Connection object and send the value returned by the getVideoState()
> method of the ConnectionRequest object.
> onCreateIncomingConnectionFailed(PhoneAccountHandle,
> ConnectionRequest) The telecom subsystem calls this method when your
> app calls the addNewIncomingCall(PhoneAccountHandle, Bundle) method to
> inform Telecom of a new incoming call, but the incoming call isn't
> permitted (for more information, see calling constraints). Your app
> should silently reject the incoming call, optionally posting a
> notification to inform the user of the missed call.